# How to fix cannot ready property of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

So, i've been coding a discord bot, and i'm getting this error when trying to check if "mrole" has the property "app". I have no idea why this is not working.

I want it to read the team's id so i can sort out the json file like this:

```
      let barney = message.guild.roles.find(r => r.name === "Barney")
      let deadpool = message.guild.roles.find(r => r.name === "Deadpool")
      let hulk = message.guild.roles.find(r => r.name === "Hulk")
      let mario = message.guild.roles.find(r => r.name === "Mario")
      let spiderman = message.guild.roles.find(r => r.name === "Spider-Man")
      let umbreon = message.guild.roles.find(r => r.name === "Umbreon")
      let app = message.guild.member(message.mentions.users.first());
      let app2 = message.mentions.users.first().username
      var mrole
      if (app.roles.has(barney.id)){
        mrole = barney.id
      }
      else if (app.roles.has(deadpool.id)){
        mrole = deadpool.id
      }
      else if (app.roles.has(hulk.id)){
        mrole = hulk.id
      }
      else if (app.roles.has(mario.id)){
        mrole = mario.id
      }
      else if (app.roles.has(spiderman.id)){
        mrole = spiderman.id
      }
      else if (app.roles.has(umbreon.id)){
        mrole = umbreon.id
      }
      if(mrole = barney.id || deadpool.id || hulk.id || mario.id || spiderman.id || umbreon.id){
          if (client.memberspoints.mrole[app.id].name != app2){
          client.memberspoints [mrole] = {
            [app2.id]: {
              name: `${app2}`, 
              mpoints: `${+args[1]}`
            }  
          }
          message.channel.send(`${app} agora tem ${+args[1]} pontos`);
          }
            else{
              let _mpoints = client.memberspoints.mrole[app.id].mpoints
              var smpoints = +_mpoints + +args[1]
              client.memberspoints [mrole] = {
                [app.id]:{
                  name: `${app2}`,
                  mpoints: `${smpoints}`
                }
              }
              message.channel.send(`${app} agora tem ${smpoints} pontos`);
            }
            fs.writeFile ('./memberspoints.json', JSON.stringify (client.memberspoints, null, 2), err => {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log('Salvo');
            });
```

Here is the error i'm geting:
`if (client.memberspoints.mrole[app.id].name != app2){
                               ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'app.id' of undefined`

I basically want it to check if the "mrole" already has the name of the person on it, so i an sort it out by team and by name. Any ideas?

Comment: So, you say there is an error.  Where is it?  You have not given us anything information explaining the code or where the error is.  Its not reproducible because we dont have the environment since are you have custom roles etc.

Comment: Added, it. That was my bad, sorry.

Comment: `app` seems to be an object. So, what is the purpose of `mrole[app]`?

Comment: `mrole` is undefined

Comment: break your code down.   Console log the app.id to ensure it is what you said it is.  Then look at mrole, and look at its properties.  mrole sounds like an object, so the `app.id` needs to be a key in that object.  If there isnt, it throws.  You would need to catch this possibility as i dont see any sort of object validation in your snippet.  I also notice that you have no else statement. Is there a plausibility that it could be undefined?

Comment: @Fallenreaper but it's not about `app.id`, but about `mrole` ... `var mrole` line doesn't make it less `undefined`.

Comment: its not about app.id, its about understanding what that value is, as it is a required key for the mrole object.  So either mrole is undefined or the value at that location is undefined

Comment: I have logged both, `mrole` and `app.id`. Both are the id's i want. I just don't get why if i replace mrole with "spiderman" for example it works normaly, but not if i use mrole...

Comment: @Ryuunosuke your if statement is off.  You cant say:  `x == a || b || c`, you have to say: `x==a||x==b||x==c`

Comment: @Ryuunosuke what is the output of: `client.memberspoints.mrole` ?  it seems that is a different object that mrole.

Comment: @Fallenreaper the problem is that it's not `==` but `=` in the ops code. It's not a comparation. So it kinda got sense... still ends up undefined, so neither of those values is.

Comment: @FlashThunder true.  Good catch, though if he is assigning in an if statement, what is the point of all the code above it.  I think there is more wrong here than first thought in terms of logic.

Comment: if the app has roles for spiderman, assign its id (and likewise for everything else).  Then you reassign it later given the if statement.  There is a usecase where ALL objects you have contain an undefined, null, etc ID, which would lead to mrole being undefined.  If it is undefined you should handle it.  I think that you shoudl do mrole assignment outside the if statement and then check to see it has been assigned to something.

Comment: @Fallenreaper tried to assign it outside the if statement, The log says it is assigned but when it tries to write it it throws the same error

Comment: @Ryuunosuke your if statement reassigns it. Try as follows:
`mrole = barney.id || deadpool.id ....; if (mrole){ ... }` If it is undefined , it wont go into that code block.  Now obviously, im not sure if mrole correlates to the values located at `client.memberspoints.mrole` or not, but that may come closer to solving it?

Comment: Is `client.memberspoints.mrole` defined? If you're trying to use the *value* of `mrole` and not read the `mrole` property of `client.memberspoints`, use bracket notation.

Comment: @Fallenreaper tried it and had no success

Answer (score 0):

To check if an object has a certain property, you should use the `object.hasOwnProperty` method:

> The hasOwnProperty() method returns a boolean indicating whether the object has the specified property as its own property (as opposed to inheriting it).

so, it would go like this:

`if(mrole.hasOwnProperty('app')) { // do stuff }`

I recently learned that in this could potentially be a security problem, so its better to use it like this: `if( Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(mrole, 'app')`. ( you can read more [here](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-prototype-builtins) ).

now, the probelm might be something else entirely- I noticed that in the line 
`if(mrole = barney.id || deadpool.id || hulk.id || mario.id || spiderman.id || umbreon.id)`, you ASSIGN to the mrole, and not comparing! should be `if(mrole == ...`

Comment: but the problem is that `mrole` is undefined, not that it doesn't have that property ..., so calling `hasOwnProperty()` on it will throw an error, like: `Cannot read property 'hasOwnProperty' of undefined`, it's better to use `typeof variable == 'undefined'`

Comment: @FlashThunder well true, althought his firstly asked question was "how do I check if an object has a certain property", so I answered on that :)
and yeah, there si a lot of wrong here now that i take another look at the code: `if` statement is wrong, mrole is undefined, there is assignment inside the `if` statement...